# Show that $ \large w= \frac{1}{k(a)} + \frac{1}{k(a+pi)}$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

How can we get $ \large w= \frac{1}{k(a)} + \frac{1}{k(a+pi)}$ by using those $4$ facts I got?

Let $y (a)$ be a simple closed planar curve with curvature $k > 0$ parametrized by $a$,
where $a$ is defined as the arclength parameter of the unit tangent field $e_1$.
Further assume that the width
$w = <e_2 (a) , (y (a + pi) − y (a))>$
is constant. Show that:

> $$ \large w= \frac{1}{k(a)} + \frac{1}{k(a+pi)}$$

Start by establishing the facts:
$$\frac{dy}{da}=\frac{e_1}{k}$$
$$\frac{de_1}{da}=e_2$$
$$\frac{de_2}{da}=-e_1$$
$$e_1(a+pi)=-e_1(a)$$

Comment: Hint: $w$ is a constant. Use this fact to get an expression for $y(a+\pi)-y(a)$.

Comment: I'm confused about the＂＜,＞＂，it's dot product？

Comment: Yes, that "<,>" is an inner product. BTW, you should edit the pi in your post.